# prestashop hook actionProductSave exec code

Tags: hook, prestashop

Hi I dont fully understand to hooks in prestashop 1.0.6.9.

For example where i found the code which is executed when

```
Hook::exec('actionProductSave', array('id_product' => $this->id));
```

from Product class in add method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hooks can be used by modules. There are two types of hooks:

> - action: These hooks are triggered by specific events that take place in PrestaShop
> - display: These hooks result in something being displayed, either in the front-end or the back-end

More info about hooks:

- [Hooks in PrestaShop 1.5](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Hooks+in+PrestaShop+1.5)
- [Understanding and using hooks](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS14/Understanding+and+using+hooks)

You can check which modules use the `actionProductSave` hook in `PrestaShop back-office` -> `Modules` -> `Positions`. None of the core modules use it.